# How can I download multiple objects from S3 simultaneously?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have lots (millions) of small log files in s3 in with its name (date/time) helping to define it i.e. servername-yyyy-mm-dd-HH-MM. e.g.

```
s3://my_bucket/uk4039-2015-05-07-18-15.csv
s3://my_bucket/uk4039-2015-05-07-18-16.csv
s3://my_bucket/uk4039-2015-05-07-18-17.csv
s3://my_bucket/uk4039-2015-05-07-18-18.csv
...
s3://my_bucket/uk4339-2015-05-07-19-23.csv
s3://my_bucket/uk4339-2015-05-07-19-24.csv
...
etc
```

From EC2, using the [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html), I would like to simultaneously download all files that are have the minute equal 16 for 2015, for all only server uk4339 and uk4338

Is there a clever way to do this?

Also if this is a terrible file structure in s3 to query data, I would be extremely grateful for any advice on how to set this up better.

I can put a relevant `aws s3 cp ...` command into a loop in a shell/bash script to sequentially download the relevant files but, was wondering if there was something more efficient.

As an added bonus I would like to row bind the results together too as one csv.

A quick example of a mock csv file can be generated in R using this line of R code

```
R> write.csv(data.frame(cbind(a1=rnorm(100),b1=rnorm(100),c1=rnorm(100))),file='uk4339-2015-05-07-19-24.csv',row.names=FALSE)
```

The csv that is created is `uk4339-2015-05-07-19-24.csv`. FYI, I will be importing the combined data into R at the end.

Comment: I don't know S3, but tell me how to generate a list of all your files in S3, and how to copy one of them and I'll do my best to show you a way to do it really fast...

Comment: To rowbind could you simply cat all the CSVs together (stripping the header) and read that as a single CSV? If so, it might be a good idea to do that after you copy each file.

Answer (score 6):

As you didn't answer my questions, nor indicate what OS you use, it is somewhat hard to make any concrete suggestions, so I will briefly suggest you use GNU Parallel to parallelise your S3 fetch requests to get around the latency.

Suppose you somehow generate a list of all the S3 files you want and put the resulting list in a file called `GrabMe.txt` like this

```
s3://my_bucket/uk4039-2015-05-07-18-15.csv
s3://my_bucket/uk4039-2015-05-07-18-16.csv
s3://my_bucket/uk4039-2015-05-07-18-17.csv
s3://my_bucket/uk4039-2015-05-07-18-18.csv
```

Then you can get them in parallel, say 32 at a time, like this:

```
parallel -j 32 echo aws s3 cp {} . < GrabMe.txt
```

or if you prefer reading left-to-right

```
cat GrabMe.txt | parallel -j 32 echo aws s3 cp {} .
```

You can obviously alter the number of parallel requests from 32 to any other number. At the moment, it just `echo`es the command it would run, but you can remove the word `echo` when you see how it works.

There is a good tutorial [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html), and Ole Tange (the author of GNU Parallel) is on SO, so we are in good company.

Comment: cat GrabMe.txt | parallel -jk 32  'aws s3 cp {} .; grep -v \" {}' > big.csv

Comment: Based on that example above what is the reason to start 32 processes/threads to upload 4 files?

Comment: It's just an example - I thought you had hundreds/thousands/millions of files or more.

Comment: Running this command shown above results in printing to console of the content of the file but nothing downloads. Any ideas?

Comment: @ErikR As it is, it just echoes/prints the command it would run because of the `echo` statement. If the output looks correct, run it again without the `echo`.

Comment: Output looked good, I removed the `echo` but got this error on osx: `aws: error: the following arguments are required: paths`. It looks like it's not receiving the `{}` as a parameter. What I did to solve it was to prepare the whole command with `awk` first: `cat GrabMe.txt | awk '{ printf "aws s3 cp %s . \n",$0 }' | parallel -j 16`